# Getting wrong Month when using new Date() type

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

## What I want to do:

I want to create a new Date().

### My Code:

```
checkDates (currentRecSec: RecommendedSection){
       var currActiveFrom = new Date(currentRecSec.activeFrom.year,currentRecSec.activeFrom.month,currentRecSec.activeFrom.day);
       var currActiveTo = new Date(currentRecSec.activeTo.year,currentRecSec.activeTo.month,currentRecSec.activeTo.day);
}
```

### My Problem

`currentRecSec` is given in this way:

```
activeFrom: {year: 2020, month: 10, day: 1}
activeTo: {year: 2020, month: 10, day: 2}
```

What happens is that I get the following result:

`Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

`Mon Nov 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

So I get November and not October.

I know that the months start counting at 0.

But is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: `currentRecSec.activeFrom.month - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing you can do is just:

```js
var currActiveTo = new Date(currentRecSec.activeTo.year,currentRecSec.activeTo.month - 1,currentRecSec.activeTo.day);
```

But I suggest you take a look at libraries like [luxon.js](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) that allow you to work with js dates easier.

Comment: Thank you!  I was not thinking it would be this simple :D

Comment: No problem! If my answer has solved your problem, you can mark it as correct.